# Java api Process execute machine command

Tags: java, process

use java api Process exceute machine command:

```
    BufferedReader read = null;
    Process process = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        process = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", command}).start();
        //stderr
        printExecStdErr(command, process);
        //stdout
        read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lineNumber++ > 1) {
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            sb.append(line);
        }
        String result=sb.toString();
        logger.info("excute command:{} result:{}",command,result);
        try {
            boolean success = process.waitFor(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (!success){
                logger.warn("execute command:{} waitFor 3 seconds,timeout!");
                return "";
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           logger.error("execute command:{} interrupted exception!");
        }
        logger.info("excute command:{} success",command);
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("execute command:{} error:{}",command,e.getMessage(),e);
    } finally {
        if (null != read) {
            try {
                read.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        if (process != null){
            process.destroy();
        }
    }
```

this is the log,execute command:bin/ps -ef | grep -w 6005 | grep 
-v grep,but sometimes the result is empty

execute command:/bin/ps -ef | grep -w 6005 | grep -v grep
INFO printExecStdErr,command:/bin/ps -ef | grep -w 6005 | grep 
-v grep
INFO excute command:/bin/ps -ef | grep -w 6005 | grep -v grep 
**result**:
excute command:/bin/ps -ef | grep -w 6006 | grep -v grep success

---

the majority of the result is:
excute command:/bin/ps -ef | grep -w 26006 | grep -v grep 
**result**:work     24643     1  0 17:39 ?        00:00:00 /opt/soft/redis28/bin/redis-server *:26006

---

so how this happens? I used process.waitFor(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),but it's useless.

Comment: That line ends with `:26006`.  Why *wouldn’t* it be included in the result?

Comment: the result is:"work 24643 1 0 17:39 ? 00:00:00 /opt/soft/redis28/bin/redis-server *:26006"

Comment: The result is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: yes,the majority of the result is this,but sometimes the result is empty